# Bash Script - get User Name given UID

Tags: bash, unix, uid, etcpasswd

How - given USER ID as parameter, find out what is his name? The problem is to write a Bash script, and somehow use etc/passwd file.

Comment: What did you try? did you make an effort to solve this?

Comment: And which Linux distro are you in/

Comment: Im using Ubuntu. I thought about using cat, to get everything that is inside etc/passwd, but I dont know what do next

Comment: Can you try `getent passwd "<uid>" | cut -d: -f1` to see if it works?

Comment: It does not output anything. Shouldnt I use IFS, to specify somehow to treat ':' as a separator?

Comment: The cut `-d:` is meant for that, can you let me know if `getent passwd "<uid>"` if it is properly printing the values?

Answer (score 3):

The `uid` is the **3rd field** in `/etc/passwd`, based on that, you can use:

```
awk -v val=$1 -F ":" '$3==val{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

---

4 ways to achieve what you need:

http://www.digitalinternals.com/unix/linux-get-username-from-uid/475/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`grep ":$1:" /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d ":"`

This greps for the UID within /etc/passwd.

Alternatively you can use the getent command:

`getent passwd "$1" | cut -f 1 -d ":"`

It then does a cut and takes the first field, delimited by a colon. This first field is the username.

You might find the SS64 pages for cut and grep useful:
http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html
http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Comment: I believe that the first solution may sometimes give wrong results if the primary gid parameter for some other user if equal to the uid you are searching for.

Comment: commentor above is correct. If you want to use grep, you should instead do `grep -E "${1}:[0-9]+::"`